# Tracking pixel (transparent GIF) as a background-image in a stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

Anyone know if adding a tracking pixel (just a transparent GIF with some logging going on at the server that's sending out the GIF) as a `background-image` in a linked stylesheet will work the same as if it was a regular `<img>` on a page?

From a simple test I did in Chrome's network inspector it looks like it's just pulling images from local cache if I go into the location bar and hit enter. If I actually click Reload then I see it go out to the server and get back a 304. And if I shift+reload it'll force it to go back to the server for real and I get 200s.

But, it looks like it's the same behavior for the `<img>` images on the page as well, so then the behavior as a background-image should match the behavior as if it was an `<img>`

Comment: Seems reasonable so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a tracking pixel called via CSS would be possible, but there would be some challenges compared to using a tracking pixel in HTML:

- Tracking pixels commonly have visitor data detected by JavaScript (monitor size, for instance) added to the pixel's URL.  JavaScript would be unable to (easily) do this if the pixel was called via stylesheet.
- When in the page source, the tracking pixel can be at the bottom of the page and be modified by code that executes first.  This would be difficult to do in a single-pixel-call via CSS.

Comment: Ahh yes, I hadn't considered the JS angle. Another department in the company wants to insert a tracking pixel into one of our site's themes, but the themes are driven purely by CSS--no static images can be added. I'm not sure how complex their tracking is, but if it requires JS I guess we'll have to modify our theme system a bit.

Answer (score 2):

It should work exactly the same way. But tracking pixels are not decorative, or are specific to a single page, so it is easier to put an img tag in the HTML and a little more reliable, it will work for text browsers, etc.

Comment: Also, using `img` tags one can add a timestamped phony URI parameter (`tracker.png?time=2011.09.22.12.34.56`) to the `src`, which I expect allows avoiding any client-side cache.

Comment: @ANeves - adding random url params is normally a way to force reload of an image that has already loaded, I think.